# How to set broadcast receiver attributes programmatically?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

I'm broadcasting an intent in my app and receiving it with a broadcast receiver. I can handle the broadcasting and receiving. No problem with that. However, I want to register the receiver completely programmatically instead of doing it in the manifest file. Notice, that in the manifest file, there are two attributes of the receiver `android:enabled="true"` and `android:exported="false"`. I need to know, **how do I specifically set these two attributes** when I register the receiver programmatically?

My AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mybroadcastapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyBroadcastApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("com.example.mybroadcastapplication.EXPLICIT_INTENT");
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void broadcastIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.mybroadcastapplication.EXPLICIT_INTENT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                broadcastIntent();
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
}
```

My MyBroadcastReceiver.java file:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("com.example.mybroadcastapplication.EXPLICIT_INTENT"))
            Toast.makeText(context, "Explicit intent received.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is used for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest if you are registering/unregistering programmatically. You only need to declare `BroadcastReceiver`s in the manifest if you want them to be instantiated from external triggers (for example, on device boot, or from the Alarm Manager, etc.)

Comment: I don't want to declare the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest anyway. I intend to register/unregister it programmatically. All that I want to know is, while registering the Receiver programmatically, how do I set the `android:enabled="true"` and `android:exported="false"` attributes as being done in the manifest? What is the Java code counterpart of those two XML attributes?

Comment: There isn't one. If you register the `BroadcastReceiver` it is "enabled". If you unregister it, it is "disabled". Those attributes are only relevant for manifest-registered receivers.

Comment: OK. And what about `android:exported="false"`? Is it relevant for manifest-registered receivers only?

Comment: Yes, relevant for manifest-registered receivers only. If you dynamically register a `BroadcastReceiver`, it will be triggered based on the `IntentFilter` that you specify. If you want to prevent your `BroadcastReceiver` from being triggered by other apps, you can use `LocalBroadcastManager` for that.

Comment: @DavidWasser I have tried with `android:exported="true"` and `android:exported="false"` But non worked for me

Comment: @Moeez sorry, I don't understand your comment. Please open a new question and detail your problem there.